# Get Geo location from Title element

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to create a variable called Geo who'll show me the user location using the area code of a phone field in my form.
The area code HTML attached below.

I created this:

function flag(){
    var getTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("selected-flag").getAttribute("title");
}

but it's not working.

Any suggestions?
[The form's area code HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/896c3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. If you have only one element with such class name you can call:

```
function flag(){ 
    var getTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("selected-flag")[0].getAttribute("title");
}
```

Otherwise I would suggest using unique id for the element and calling getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually,
I got help and came up with this:

var el = document.querySelector('.selected-flag');
  return el ? el.getAttribute('title') : undefined;